# registering multiple resource provider with multiple subscription in azure using power-shell

Tags: azure, powershell, loops, subscription, azure-powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting please bear me if I am wrong somewhere.

I have 100 subscription for training purpose under one Tenant of Azure. I would like to Register with all resource providers in all subscription using powershell script. Everytime I have to change with subscription and then I can fire command for registering RP.I would like to loop this scenario so that it should start from first sub and continue till last subscripton. I tried with passing Subscription names  as CSV file but it went wrong somewhere. I am not understanding where it went wrong.

Please find the script that I made for the same. Suggestions will be much appreciated

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

$subscriptions = Import-csv -path "C:\subscriptions.csv"

Foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) 
{
    Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | where {$_.RegistrationState -eq "NotRegistered"} | Register-AzureRmResourceProvider
}

Write-Host "Subscription resource provider registration is completed"
```

Comment: Hi Suraj. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you get any error messages?   How is the actual behavior different from the expected?
Have you tried outputting  the results Get & Where before you pipe it to the Register method to see if that is working as expected?

Comment: please add `Select-AzureSubscription  -SubscriptionName <subscription name>` in the loop to ensure which subscription you use in the current loop.

Comment: Besides, could you please tell me the error message.

Comment: @JimXu I am not receiving any error message. Script executing without even registering RP. when I check with RP in subs it was not registered.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I tried with following two command manually  select-azurermsubscription <subscription_name>Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | where {$_.RegistrationState -eq "NotRegistered"} | Register-AzureRmResourceProvider and it is working fine

Comment: @SurajChopde Since the issue has been resolved bt yourself, could you please post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I summary the solution as below.

When you run the PowerShell script to register resource providers, we should run `Select-AzureRmSubscription` at the first to choose the subscription now we use.
For example

My test CSV file

[image]

Script

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

$subs=import-csv -Path 'D:\sub.csv'
foreach($sub in $subs){

  Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $sub.SubscriptionName
   Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | where {$_.RegistrationState -eq "NotRegistered"} | Register-AzureRmResourceProvider
}
```

[image]

Besides, please note that when we run the script, we need to ensure that the account we use to login should be the owner of the subscriptions in the csv file.